# On a SQL Delete that joins multiple tables, will all tables be affected?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to join several tables, but I want only to delete lines from the 
threadsread table. I got the following SQL that showsthe lines I want to delete.

```
SELECT * FROM threadsread tr, threads t WHERE 
tr.tid=t.tid and tr.uid=2111 and t.fid=30
```

On [Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) it states: 
"*For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions.*"

Getting the above select to a delete , will the threads table be also affected?

```
DELETE FROM threadsread tr, threads t 
WHERE tr.tid=t.tid and tr.uid=2111 and t.fid=30
```

If it will, how can I get only the threadsread table affected?

Answer (score 2):

In many (maybe most or all) SQL flavors, the delete statement you provide is actually invalid.  Instead use:

```
DELETE FROM threadsread tr
USING threads t
WHERE tr.tid=t.tid AND tr.uid=2111 AND t.fid=30;
```

This makes it obvious that you are only deleting from the one table specified in the 'FROM' clause.

Comment: I got sql as:  
DELETE FROM `threadsread` tr
USING `threads` t
Where
tr.tid=t.tid and tr.uid in (2111, 2564, 2326, 2510) and t.fid=30
I took the prefix out. And I get a "#1109 - Unknown table 'mybb_threadsread' in MULTI DELETE"

Comment: I tried not using aliases as mentioned on this article:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/07/how-to-write-multi-table-cross-database-deletes-with-aliases-in-mysql/

DELETE FROM `mybb_threadsread` 
USING `mybb_threads` t
Where
mybb_threadsread.tid=mybb_threads.tid and mybb_threadsread.uid in (2111, 2564, 2326, 2510) and mybb_threads.fid=30

But I still get the exactly same message...

Comment: It sure sounds like 'mybb_threadsread' isn't a table.  My best guesses: It's a typo, or it's not a table, but a view, or some other table-like object. (I don't know if MySQL would behave this way if you tried to delete from a view or not)

Comment: no, its not a view nor a typo. It works on the select command...
Some of the info I got here:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/07/how-to-write-multi-table-cross-database-deletes-with-aliases-in-mysql/